# OnUpdate NEVER called - Android Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have been following various Widget Tutorials such as [this one](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Creating-a-Home-Screen-App-Widget-on-Android-3833306.htm) and [this one](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html)

I have tried adapting their code to my purposes, and I have tried straight-up copy paste.
It seems no matter what I do, my widget NEVER gets updated. When it is placed on the home screen the text stays as the Static Text it was created with.
All I need this app to do is update 4 TextViews which will be contained in the layout.

The code below is mostly copied from one of the tutorials. I've tried debugging the onUpdate method, however the break point never seems to be hit.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

EDIT: I reverted to a much simpler version of this widget that I was trying earlier in my efforts and replaced the code below with the code for the simpler widget. I made the changes suggested by CommonsWare to my manifest. Unfortunately the problem remains.

My main .java file looks like so:

```
public class NetStatWidget extends AppWidgetProvider 
{

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager manager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{   
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, NetStatWidget.class);
    int[] widgetId = manager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView0, "Hello");
    manager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteView);
}

}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.stat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


            <receiver android:name="NetStatWidget" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data 
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/providerinfo" />
            </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my Widget Provider Info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
android:minWidth="146dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="10000">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your manifest is wrong. You are claiming that you have a `network.widget.AppWidgetProvider` class, and AFAIK, you don't. You have an oddly-named `network.widget.NetworkWidgetActivity` class. You need to use *that* in your `<receiver>` element.

Also:

- Replace `this.getApplicationContext()` and `getApplicationContext()` with `this`
- Unless you plan on doing more serious work in the service (database I/O, network I/O, etc.), consider just moving all that logic into `onUpdate()` and getting rid of the service, since it's not really buying you much here (and if you *are* going to keep the service, switch to an `IntentService` and get rid of `stopSelf()` since that's handled for you)
- While you are asking for 10-second updates, the minimum effective `updatePeriodMillis` is 30 minutes -- just keep that in mind while you are debugging
- `int[] widgetId` seems to be unused in `NetworkWidgetActivity`
- `onStart()` in a `Service` has been deprecated for a couple of years; use `onStartCommand()` instead

Comment: I changed my manifest as per your suggestion and Im still having the same issue...I reverted back to a simpler widget I was trying at the beginning of my efforts, made that same change and it is having the same problem. I edited the code above the reflect the simpler code. Do you see the same issue?

Comment: @Jodron: No, what you have there should work on Android 3.0 and below. Android 3.1 and above, you need an activity to go with your app widget -- your app widget will receive no broadcasts until the user runs the activity. This directory contains another two app widget samples, both of which work: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget

Comment: That is just strange. Im running it on 2.3, and it still won't update the text. Am I wrong in thinking that as soon as the widget is placed "textView0" should read "Hello"? 
Thanks for the examples, Ill look through those and see if I can't figure it out. I think I might in over my head and should just make it a regular app.

Comment: @Jodron: "Am I wrong in thinking that as soon as the widget is placed "textView0" should read "Hello"?" -- well, within a second or so, assuming there is a `TextView` named `@+id/textView0` in `res/layout/appwidget.xml`. Though the code you have listed there will not compile, as there is no `widgetId`. Consider temporarily switching to the version of `updateAppWidget()` that takes the `ComponentName`, so you aren't getting lost in app widget IDs.

Comment: Changing the updateAppWidget to use a component name fixed it! Thank you very much for helping me through that cloud of ignorance. Now to spend another 5 hours teaching myself how to fill those textViews with network info. Thanks again citizen.